# How Can I Have View-Specific <head> contents Using Asp.Net MVC 3 and Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, stylesheet

I want to link a specific style sheet in certain Views in addition to what already gets linked in _Layout.cshtml.  For non-Razor, I see using the content place holder.  How would I do this for Razor?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The equivalent of content placeholders in Razor are sections.

In your _Layout.cshtml:

```
<head>
@RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
</head>
```

Then in your content page:

```
@section Styles {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/StandardSize.css")" />
}
```

---

An alternative solution would be to put your styles into ViewBag/ViewData:

In your _Layout.cshtml:

```
<head>
    @foreach(string style in ViewBag.Styles ?? new string[0]) {
        <link href="@Url.Content(style)" />
    }
</head>
```

And in your content page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Styles = new[] { "~/Content/StandardSize.css" };
}
```

This works because the view page gets executed before the layout.

Comment: This is also a great way to add view specific script references to the head.

Comment: The alternate solution is good for folks who have not yet converted their solution to use Razor.  Thanks!