# Don't apply css on specific page

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

Is it possible and how to do not apply css on specific web page?

---

For example, i have some div's on Master Page and some css for them

`.header {...}`

But i have also some page (Home page), which is different from all site-style.

So i don't want to appy css from Master Page and i don't want overwrite existing css rules like this :

`#specific.header{...}`

---

*Maybe there is solution such as add new Master Page.*

---

Is it good to add some css using JS before page is loaded?

Comment: Maybe you want to have different `.css` files for each page ?

Comment: You could add a new Master Page, so the new page inherits from that, instead of the base Master page?

Comment: To me it sounds like you are doing it wrong if your homepage styles are completely different from the rest of your site.

Comment: that's not possible.you can write inline css

Comment: @Radian You want to keep content separate from presentation ;-)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493116/how-to-add-individual-css-file-in-particular-view-in-mvc4) and [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739907/how-can-i-have-view-specific-head-contents-using-asp-net-mvc-3-and-razor) would help you.

Comment: @danyel hm..) maybe it's helps

Comment: It is possible in Wordpress, but I don't know if you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try any of these options:

- Wrap all your standard pages under a `<div id="whatever">`, except the specific page you want free of your general css. Then prefix your css rules with #whatever, so `a {color:red;}` would be `#whatever a {color:red}`

This approach is very easy using LESS, because there is no need of prefixing every rule, just wrap them inside `#whatever {  ALL YOUR RULES}`

- Dynamically loading of your css, via JS or your server logic if you are using any MVC flavoured framework.